# Rigify Human Rig, No rig main properties Panel

Tags: interface, rigify

[image]

[image]

I want this panel above. To control the IK and FK. But for some reason when I generate the rig, the dropdown is just empty, and when restarting the project I get the above error

Comment: Turns out, You need to turn on a layer, and when that layer is turned on only then does my rig main properties show up or else not. This is what worked for me, Iand ofcourse I did allow execution everytime but nothing happened. I even messed with the rig id and stuffs

Answer (score 2):

The error is because by default Blender will now allow Python scripts to automatically execute, but rigify requires the script `rig_ui.py` to execute to generate the interface panel.

If you click "Allow Execution" the script should run and the UI will appear.

Comment: That setting can be changed globally in Blender if required by checking Edit > Preferences > Save & Load > Auto Run Python Scripts and saving the preferences.

Comment: @JohnEason Indeed.  If you look at the popup in the screen shot, there's a checkbox to do that without having to edit preferences.  (I'm not sure in what release that was added.)  As always, be warned that auto-execute is a security risk and you have to be careful about what blend files you open when you have it set.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying y'all.